# GitHub Actions: Move branch to another branch

Tags: github, continuous-integration, github-actions

So I'm working on a project where I have a number of Sass stylesheets, and I want to host it on GitHub Pages. I've pointed Pages to the `gh-pages` branch, and when I make a change I am trying to set up Actions to 'teleport' that branch to my freshly-pushed `main` source code branch, make a commit containing the generation of new CSS files from the Sass source code, and push that to the `gh-pages` branch for Pages to host. This way I know it has started from the latest version of the source, with no leftover generated files, and run a single deterministic compilation to create the CSS files I'm after.

I've been able to set this up, but the only way I've been able to get it working is by deleting the `gh-pages` branch, checking out the `main` branch, recreating `gh-pages` and committing from there. The problem with this is that, when the `gh-pages` branch gets deleted, GitHub Pages stops tracking it and moves back to the `main` branch. Here's the workflow anyway, just for reference:

```yaml
name: Compile Sass

on:
  push:
    branches:
      - main

jobs:
  build_css:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest

    steps:
      - name: Checkout source Git branch
        uses: actions/checkout@v2
        with:
            ref: main
            fetch-depth: 10
            submodules: true
      
      - name: Delete gh-pages branch
        uses: dawidd6/action-delete-branch@v3
        with:
          github_token: ${{ secrets.GITHUB_TOKEN }}
          branches: gh-pages
      
      - name: Create fresh gh-pages branch
        uses: peterjgrainger/action-create-branch@v2.0.1
        env:
          GITHUB_TOKEN: ${{ secrets.GITHUB_TOKEN }}
        with:
          branch: 'gh-pages'

      - name: Checkout new gh-pages branch
        uses: actions/checkout@v2
        with:
            ref: gh-pages
            fetch-depth: 1

      - name: Compile CSS from SCSS files
        uses: gha-utilities/sass-build@v0.4.5
        with:
          source: styles/index.scss
          destination: styles/index.css

      - name: Add and commit changes to gh-pages branch
        run: |
          git config --local user.email 'action@github.com'
          git config --local user.name 'GitHub Action'
          git add styles/*
          git commit -m 'Compile website'

      - name: Push changes
        uses: ad-m/github-push-action@master
        with:
          github_token: ${{ secrets.GITHUB_TOKEN }}
          branch: gh-pages
```

Solutions I've tried using `git rebase` and `git reset` haven't worked for a range of reasons, and I've found that the former (using `git rebase --onto main gh-pages gh-pages`) works on my local machine but not in CI.

I feel like this must be a reasonably normal thing to want to do, so are there any more widely-accepted methods that I've missed?

Comment: This is almost certainly due to the use of the `checkout@v2` action, which performs a *shallow clone*. Shallow clones are useful for building, but have limitations, such as the inability to do rebases. Make the clone deeper, or don't do shallow at all (there are three options here, including using `checkout@v1` which doesn't do a shallow clone, or setting the depth for the v2 checkout, or using explicit deepening; note that shallow clones are single-branch clones).

Comment: Thank you @torek! That's sorted it :)